# Construct a matrix of polynomials to optimize condition-like score

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I'm a physicist currently working on my PhD. Within my studies, my colleagues & I encountered a (strictly mathematical) problem that baffles us (and anyone else we've talked to so far) and is also sort of a showstopper for our studies. We'd like to use this as a forum to ask people with more expertise in linear algebra & numerics than our immediate social circle for suggestions and opinions on this problem.

## The Problem

Consider an expression 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L} & = & \left(\sum_{g\in G_{1}}g\right)^{2}\cdot\left(\sum_{g\in G_{2}}g\right)^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $G_{1}$and $G_{2}$ are possibly overlapping sets of parameters
$g\in\vec{g}$, where $\vec{g}\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$. After expanding,
this expression takes the form
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L} & = & \sum_{i}c_{i}P_{i}\left(\vec{g}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
where the $c_{i}$ absorb all the numerical constants arising from
the expansion and the $P_{i}$ are polynomials of the type $P_{i}=g_{\alpha}g_{\beta}g_{\gamma}g_{\delta}$
where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in1,\dots,N$. With these polynominals
a matrix is constructed 
\begin{eqnarray*}
M=\left(\begin{matrix}P_{1}\left(\vec{g}_{1}\right) & \cdots & P_{1}\left(\vec{g}_{n}\right)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
P_{n}\left(\vec{g}_{1}\right) & \cdots & P_{n}\left(\vec{g}_{n}\right)
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

For a given region $X$, we have to find a set $S$ of vectors $\vec{g}_{i}\in S$ ($i=1,\dots,n$)
with $g_{i,j},\ j=1,\dots,N$ such that

\begin{eqnarray*}
 & \min_{S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times N}}\left(\left\Vert M^{-1}\right\Vert _{X}\cdot\left\Vert M\right\Vert _{X}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert _{X}$ is defined as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\Vert A\right\Vert _{X} & = & \inf\left\{ c>0:\left\Vert Av\right\Vert \leq c\left\Vert v\right\Vert \forall v\in I\left(X\right)\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\right\} 
\end{eqnarray*}

where $I\left(X\right)$ is the image of the map $x:\vec{g}\to\left(P_{i}\left(\vec{g}\right)\right)_{i\le n}$.

**Remark:** We have *borrowed* the definition of the minimized quantity from the condition number. The reason why we don't want to use the condition number directly is that we already know the region $X$ in which we will want to evaluate our method, thus optimizing with respect to this particular region is favorable. If the solution to this problem would become significantly simpler when dropping this additional constraint and using the real condition number instead, that would also be an option.

## Simple Example

For illustration, we have constructed a simple show-case example. For realistic applications, the matrices will be much larger (up to 1600x1600). But even for this simple example, finding a solution is not straight-forward. Consider an expression
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{L} & = & g_{1}^{2}\left(g_{2}+g_{3}\right)^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
such that $P_{1}\left(\vec{g}\right)=g_{1}^{2}g_{2}^{2}$ and $P_{2}\left(\vec{g}\right)=g_{1}^{2}g_{3}^{2}$
and $P_{3}\left(\vec{g}\right)=g_{1}^{2}g_{2}g_{3}$. Hence, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
M=\left(\begin{matrix}P_{1}\left(\vec{g}_{1}\right) & P_{1}\left(\vec{g}_{2}\right) & P_{1}\left(\vec{g}_{3}\right)\\
P_{2}\left(\vec{g}_{1}\right) & P_{2}\left(\vec{g}_{2}\right) & P_{2}\left(\vec{g}_{3}\right)\\
P_{3}\left(\vec{g}_{1}\right) & P_{3}\left(\vec{g}_{2}\right) & P_{3}\left(\vec{g}_{3}\right)
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}g_{1,1}^{2}g_{1,2}^{2} & g_{2,1}^{2}g_{2,2}^{2} & g_{3,1}^{2}g_{3,2}^{2}\\
g_{1,1}^{2}g_{1,3}^{2} & g_{2,1}^{2}g_{2,3}^{2} & g_{3,1}^{2}g_{3,3}^{2}\\
g_{1,1}^{2}g_{1,2}g_{1,3} & g_{2,1}^{2}g_{2,2}g_{2,3} & g_{3,1}^{2}g_{3,2}g_{3,3}
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, $S=\left\{ \vec{g}_{1}=\left(g_{1,1},g_{1,2},g_{1,3}\right),\vec{g}_{2}=\left(g_{2,1},g_{2,2},g_{2,3}\right),\vec{g}_{3}=\left(g_{3,1},g_{3,2},g_{3,3}\right)\right\} $.

Let us now consider a region $X=\left\{ \left(g_{1},g_{2},g_{3}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}\vert ag_{1}^{2}+bg_{2}^{2}+cg_{3}^{2}\leq1\right\} $
for some fixed values $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. Find $S$ such that

\begin{eqnarray*}
 & \min_{S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times N}}\left(\left\Vert M^{-1}\right\Vert _{X}\cdot\left\Vert M\right\Vert _{X}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

For the simplest case, consider $a=b=c=1$.

## Naive Solution

Our first attempted solution was a brute-force numeric one, using the **gsl** minimization library.
However, this naive solution has several shortcomings, as it does not converge in acceptable time and is highly inefficient.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/SVD>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_multimin.h>

using Eigen::Matrix3d;
using Eigen::Vector3d;
using Eigen::JacobiSVD;

#define PI 3.1415926

const int nvars = 9;
const double shift = 1e-5;

void getMatrix3d(Matrix3d& target, const Vector3d& g1,const Vector3d& g2,const Vector3d& g3){
  target(0,0) = g1[0]*g1[0]*g1[1]*g1[1];
  target(0,1) = g2[0]*g2[0]*g2[1]*g2[1];
  target(0,2) = g3[0]*g3[0]*g3[1]*g3[1];
  target(1,0) = g1[0]*g1[0]*g1[2]*g1[2];
  target(1,1) = g2[0]*g2[0]*g2[2]*g2[2];
  target(1,2) = g3[0]*g3[0]*g3[2]*g3[2];
  target(2,0) = g1[0]*g1[0]*g1[1]*g1[2];
  target(2,1) = g2[0]*g2[0]*g2[1]*g2[2];
  target(2,2) = g3[0]*g3[0]*g3[1]*g3[2];
}


void setVector(Vector3d& v, double r1, double r2, double r3, double phi, double theta){
  v[0] = r1*cos(phi)*cos(theta);
  v[1] = r2*sin(phi)*cos(theta);
  v[2] = r3*sin(theta);
}

void print_gsl(const gsl_vector* vec){
  for(size_t i=0; i<vec->size; ++i){
    std::cout << vec->data[i] << " , ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
double abs_gsl(const gsl_vector* vec){
  double result;
  for(size_t i=0; i<vec->size; ++i){
    result += vec->data[i]*vec->data[i];
  }
  return sqrt(result);
}



double condition(const Matrix3d& A){
  JacobiSVD<Matrix3d> svd(A);
  return svd.singularValues()(0) / svd.singularValues()(svd.singularValues().size()-1);
}

double norm(Matrix3d& m){
  double x = 0;
  static Vector3d myvec;
  for(double phi=0; phi<2*PI; phi+=0.02*PI){
    for(double theta=0; theta<PI; theta+=0.01*PI){
      setVector(myvec,1,1,1,phi,theta);
      x = std::max((m * myvec).norm(),x);
    } 
  }
  return x;
}

double f(const gsl_vector *v, void* /*params*/){
  Vector3d x1(gsl_vector_get(v, 0),gsl_vector_get(v, 1),gsl_vector_get(v, 2));
  Vector3d x2(gsl_vector_get(v, 3),gsl_vector_get(v, 4),gsl_vector_get(v, 5));
  Vector3d x3(gsl_vector_get(v, 6),gsl_vector_get(v, 7),gsl_vector_get(v, 8));
  static Matrix3d m;
  getMatrix3d(m,x1,x2,x3);
  double val = condition(m);
  if(val != val) return std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
  return val;
}

void df(const gsl_vector *v, void* /*params*/, gsl_vector *df){
  double val = f(v, NULL);
  static gsl_vector* v_shift = gsl_vector_alloc(nvars);
  for(size_t i=0;i<v->size;++i){
    for(size_t j=0;j<v->size;++j){
      if(i!=j) gsl_vector_set(v_shift, j, gsl_vector_get(v,j));
      else     gsl_vector_set(v_shift, i, gsl_vector_get(v,i)+shift);
    }
    double thisdf = (val-f(v_shift, NULL))/shift;
    gsl_vector_set(df, i, thisdf);
  }
}

void fdf(const gsl_vector *x, void* /*params*/, double *thisf, gsl_vector *thisdf){
  *thisf = f(x, NULL); 
  df(x, NULL, thisdf);
}

int main(){
  size_t iter = 0;
  int status;

  gsl_multimin_function_fdf func;
  func.n = nvars;
  func.f = &f;
  func.df = &df;
  func.fdf = &fdf;
  func.params = NULL;

  /* Starting point */
  gsl_vector *x;
  x = gsl_vector_alloc(nvars);

  gsl_vector_set (x, 0,  1.); // sample1 gHgg
  gsl_vector_set (x, 1,  1.); // sample1 gSM
  gsl_vector_set (x, 2,  0); // sample1 gBSM

  gsl_vector_set (x, 3,  1.); // sample2 gHgg
  gsl_vector_set (x, 4,  1.); // sample2 gSM
  gsl_vector_set (x, 5,  1.); // sample2 gBSM

  gsl_vector_set (x, 6,  1.); // sample3 gHgg
  gsl_vector_set (x, 7,  1.); // sample3 gSM
  gsl_vector_set (x, 8, -1.); // sample3 gBSM

  const gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_type *T;
  T = gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_steepest_descent;
  gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer *s;
  s = gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_alloc(T, nvars);

  gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_set(s, &func, x, 1e20/* step size */, 0.1/* tolerance */);

  do{
    iter++;
    status = gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_iterate(s);
    if(status){
      std::cout<<"status "<<status<<std::endl;
      break;
    }

    status = gsl_multimin_test_gradient(s->gradient, 0.1);

  }while (status == GSL_CONTINUE && iter < 1e8);

  if (status == GSL_SUCCESS)
    printf ("Minimum found at:\n");
  else 
    printf("finished with status %d after %d iterations\n",status,iter);

  gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_free(s);
  gsl_vector_free(x);

  return 0;
}
```

## Goal

As the ultimate goal is implementing this method in a C++ code environment, a numeric (or even heuristic) solution would be perfectly acceptable. However, given that the number of parameters is extremely large for realistic problems, we do not expect a brute-force approach to be feasible. A closed-form solution would of course be great, but we do not really expect this problem to be sufficiently well-behaved.
With this post, we are looking for ideas on how to tackle this problem (or parts of it) using mathematical identities or advanced numerical algorithms we are unaware of. 
Any help, including pointers to literature concerned with similar problems, is highly appreciated.